# Get the list of WiFi access points in J2ME

Tags: java, java-me, symbian, wifi

To the developers under J2ME.

Is it possible to get a list of all available WiFi points in the moment in Java? Class IAPInfo gives me just a list of available network connections, where there are different internet and other connections, such as internet.mts.ru etc. and besides there is the connection 'Search for WLAN' (like so) and there are no access points themselves there. Already seen examples of a list of WiFi points in C + + for Symbian, but I'm writing in Java. I need a list of access points to define an exact position of mobile phone. I know about cellular communications and GPS, but I also need WiFi.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get a list directly from J2ME.

A better idea is to use JSR 179's [`LocationProvider`](http://www.forum.nokia.com/document/Java_Developers_Library_v2/GUID-4AEC8DAF-DDCC-4A30-B820-23F2BA60EA52/javax/microedition/location/LocationProvider.html) which will use any means at its disposal to provide you with a location reading (this may or may not include WIFI locating).